# Configure a NiFi processor using an external file

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using NiFi to chain several API calls. I would make my flow more configurable, by setting the API keys/endpoints in an external configuration file (for example JSON, or even the `nifi.properties` file).

How can I use the informations in this config file in the properties of my processors?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently the easiest way to do this is by setting values in bootstrap.conf which are then available through NiFi expression language. For example, if you created a new java arg like:

```
java.arg.15=-DmyProperty=myValue
```

Then in your processor, your properties need to support expression language. This is done on the property descriptor builder:

```
.expressionLanguageSupported(true)
```

Then from the UI you would set the value of that property to ${myProperty}

In a future release there is going to be a new capability to make this a little easier where you can have an external properties file that will be loaded and accessible from expression language, so you won't have to edit bootstrap.conf, but for now this is the approach.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! It will do the job for the moment, I will keep an eye on this feature in future releases!